# How can I do that unitofwork in actionfilter shouldnt save objects is changed in action

Tags: .net-core, unit-of-work, action-filter

I use unitofwork pattern and its lifecycle is scope. I have lots of method as below in my controller.I bring object change property and save it then I return that object finally afteractionfilter runs and log and save it.My problem is that unitofwork what I called in filter.It saves also user object which is in action I musn't save that object.How can I solve this problem

```vb
public IActionResult ReadUserProfileImage(string id) {

     IActionResult response = BadRequest();

     var user =  unitOfWork.User.FirstOrtDefault(u=>u.id==id);
     user.Name="New name";
     return Ok(user);
}

public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext) {

     unitOfWork.Logs.Add(new CoreHelper.Core.Domain.Log() {
          User = user,
          ResultType = resultType,
          Time = time,
          Controller = controller,
          Action = action,
          Request = requestJson,
          Response = responseJson,
          Ip = ip.ToString(),
          PcName = pcName,
          Url = url,
          ProcessTime = processTime,
          LogCaption = logCaption,
          LogDetail = logDetail,
          IsBefore = isBefore
     });

     unitOfWork.Save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want any changes that you might do on the Entity, you can use the `.AsNoTracking()` option.

```
public IActionResult ReadUserProfileImage(string id) {

     IActionResult response = BadRequest();

     var user =  unitOfWork.User.AsNoTracking().FirstOrtDefault(u=>u.id==id);
     user.Name="New name";
     return Ok(user);
}
```

Comment: but in project there are a lot of method like that I can not write asnotracking for all of them.I need to control on actionfilter

Comment: The only way i can see it, is that your `UnitOfWork.Logs` for the `ActionFilter` is using a different DbContext then all the others methods. Can you show your UnitOfWork type?